# Hibernate Envers Performance and Transaction Management in a Spring Application

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

In our SpringBoot project (which uses Spring MVC, Spring Data etc.), we are using Hibernate Envers for auditing our database records. 
There are a couple of things I am not sure of.

1- Performance - Threading:

Assume I have a Person entity that is audited. When I insert/update a new Person record in the related table, how does this affect my app's performance? Will the client have to wait for all the envers auditing to complete? Will Envers handle this in a separate thread? And once the insert is successful, then the client will be able to go on with whatever task he has been doing? Or will all that auditing be handled in a single thread and the client app will have to wait for all the audit recording to be completed?

2- Performance - Cache and do:

Does Envers cache all the audit processing and perform that at a later time? I mean after all the recording has been completed.

3- Transaction Management:

How about transaction management. Let's say I have successfully created a record for the Person entity, but there was an error while trying to create the audit records. What would happen then? Would that rollback the recording of the Person entity data?

4- Distributed transaction management:

How about a distributed transaction environment? How would you make sure the consistency of envers audit records in a distributed transaction environment? Have you ever been in a similar situation and how have you resolved your problems if any?

What are the problems -if there are any- that you have experienced while using Envers. What are the alternative auditing approaches that you have applied?

Please don't just provide links and say "read this". Tell me what you know and what you have experienced.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When I insert/update in the related table, how does this affect my app's performance?

Hibernate has two high-level modes of operation: Stateful and Stateless.

When Hibernate is operating in Stateful (e.g. `Session` not `StatelessSession`) mode, it always collects entity operations into an action queue.  This action queue is used later on to drive an event system that not only causes Hiberante to execute the SQL for those operations but to also notify integrators of these entity operations as well.

The action queue has numerous goals in mind.  But when it comes to performance, its allows Hibernate to collection those operations and delay database operations so that connection acquisition and usage is minimized and so that database operations can potentially be performed in bulk.

> Will the client have to wait for all the envers auditing to complete?
>   Envers handle this in a separate thread?

Yes the client will have to wait as Envers runs in the same thread boundary as your `Session`.

> And once the insert is successful, then the client will be able to go on with whatever task he has been doing? Or will all that auditing be handled in a single thread and the client app will have to wait for all the audit recording to be completed?

Envers maintains a similar action queue much like Hibernate does.  As Hibernate flushes its action queue and fires events, Envers will be notified of those events and will build up its own action queue.

The major difference between Envers' action queue and Hibernate's is that with Envers being a commit-time audit framework, its action queue cannot be manually flushed.  The audit action queue will be automatically flushed immediately before transaction commit to guarantee all transaction operations from Hibernate have been sent to the database first.

So yes it is all single threaded.

> Does Envers cache all the audit processing and perform that at a later time? I mean after all the recording has been completed.

Yep, as I described above but I will illustrate here.  Lets assume we have an open session and an active transaction we are working with in the client:

```
// User code calls save on some entity objects
// after these operations, some action queue entries are generated 
// No SQL has been executed
// No Audit operations have been executed or generated
session.save( someEntity1 );
session.save( someEntity2 );

// Lets say we manually flush Hibernate
// This flushes the Hibernate action queue
// SQL statements get fired for the above 2 saves
// Events are fired for integrators for the 2 save operations
// Envers generates AuditWorkUnit entries in its action queue for the operations
session.flush();

// User code calls save on another entity
// after these operations, some action queue entries are generated
// No SQL has been executed for this
// No Audit operations have been executed or generated
session.save( someEntity3 );

// commit the transaction
// This flueshes the Hibernate action queue
// sQL statements get fired for the above save of someEntity3
// Events are fired for integrators for the 1 save operation
// Envers generates AuditWorkUnit entries in its action queue for the operation
// pre-commit operations fire:
//   * Envers iterates its AuditWorkUnit action queue and executes those
//   * This generates Audit table SQL operations
// Transaction gets committed if no errors
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

> How about transaction management. Let's say I have successfully created a record for the Person entity, but there was an error while trying to create the audit records. What would happen then? Would that rollback the recording of the Person entity data?

The transaction would be marked for rollback; therefore no data would be saved for `Person` or the audit equivalent for it in the audit schema.

> How about a distributed transaction environment? How would you make sure the consistency of envers audit records in a distributed transaction environment? Have you ever been in a similar situation and how have you resolved your problems if any?

That doesn't apply; let me explain.

Envers itself is super simplistic.  Those events I mentioned earlier result in a series of HQL statements being generated and handed to Hibernate for execution; nothing special there.

What that means is the same `Session` and `Transaction` you interacted with in your client's user code to send the operations to Hibernate is the same that Envers interacts with to do precisely the same.

So if that distributed transaction gets marked for rollback for whatever reason, not only is your `Person` data rolled back, so is the Envers operations themselves.  Whether the transaction is distributed or not is irrelevant to the integration between Hibernate and Envers.